# Unity Firebase Storage download Task never ends

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

The GetBytesAsync never yields any result. It never is faulted, is cancelled, or finishes. It's constantly in the status "WaitingForActivation"

```
[ConsoleCommand("test-storage")]
public static void TestDownload() {
    var storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
    StorageReference pathReference = storage.GetReference("test.txt");

    const long maxAllowedSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    pathReference.GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogException(task.Exception);
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] fileContents = task.Result;
            Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
        }
    });
}
```

this is literally the code from the firebase storage documentation.I also tried using a coroutine to wait for the task to either fail or finish. that task's status is constantly "WaitingForActivation". I've copied the exact code from the video tutorial on firebase storage as well as the one from the documentation. Neither yields any result for the task.

I tried using the exact code from Firebase Storage for Unity documentation. Task still yields no result and runs coroutine indefinitely, with status "WaitingForActivation"

I tried using the exact code from Firebase Storage for Unity's video tutorial, involving a coroutine to wait for the task. Same result.